# If a cloud company claims militairy grade security, what does that mean?

Tags: .net, encryption, cloud

What kind of security is 'military grade' or 'bank grade'?

In case of a .NET app, I can't think of much more 'security' than using basic encryption  of data and SSL, and make sure its not easy hackable...?

I'm building a webapp myself and I'm just curious when it's considered 'military' grade, even though its probably mostly a marketing term.

Comment: You kinda answered your own question with your last sentence. Also I think maybe the company is referring to their physical structure, not their software one, as the security of your apps depends mostly on your code (and solely on it, in a practical sense).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Recently, [Troy Hunt](http://www.troyhunt.com/2015/05/do-you-really-want-bank-grade-security.html) tested various Australian banks' security regarding SSL to see what "_bank grade security_" really meant. The results are interesting as well as disappointing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing. In fact, the term "military grade encryption" is regarded by a fair number of people in the security/cryptography industry as snake oil and at best it tells you marketing people who knew nothing wrote the copy for the product, at worst it suggests marketing people who knew nothing wrote the product.

There is no specific standard for "military grade encryption." If there was, they'd say they met that specific standard and give documentation.  Usually I've seen that used to mean thes software  uses AES-256. Of course, that tells you nothing. This is an image of a penguin encrypted using AES-256[image]

Not very secure, but still is "military grade." The trick is, it's done using ECB mode which isn't secure for almost all applications.

In fact, what standards actually exist are not any  better. There  is FIPS 140, which is a NIST standard originally intended for cryptographic hardware. It's applicability to software is [highly questionable](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2012/01/openssl-and-nss-are-fips-140-certified.html). In fact, ECB is a FIPS approved move, so said penguin encryption above would be valid.

There is also NSA Suite B which lists a set of algorithms for use protecting classified information. Again, it doesn't specify how to use them, and again, allows ECB mode.

Comment: Thanks :) I guess its all depends on someones interpretation

Answer (score 0):

Companies can obtain certifications that they comply with a set of security standards, a common one would be the ISO27001 standard for Information Security (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_27001:2005), although these tend to be more about the company's internal policies and procedures than their software itself.

Many larger companies or companies in security-sensitive industries (military, banking, etc.) will insist that their suppliers are certified to these sorts of standards. It usually means that you have strict policies around firewalls, passwords & access control around data, auditing, asset control etc.

As a software developer, it's worth reading up on the basic ways an application and the environment on which it's hosted can be vulnerable to attack so you know what to avoid, for example, SQL injection attacks, weak passwords, crappy cryptography (*ahem* MD5), exceptions that spit out too much information...

A good book is http://www.amazon.co.uk/Deadly-Sins-Software-Security-Programming/dp/0071626751 It's well written and informative. I've totally read some of it.

Answer (score 0):

Any such IT security claim, without reference to a *published* security standard, is just hype.

Claims regarding a level of security must be based on standards developed by established security standards organizations, such as: Payment Card Industry (PCI) Security Standards Council,  [Center For Internet Security](https://www.cisecurity.org/)